# Reshape DataFrame by slice of name in columns

Tags: python, pandas

I cannot figure out how to reshape a huge `DataFrame` with a lot of variables, latitudes and longitudes like

```
            Var1_(lat1, len1) Var2_(lat1, len1)
date1 date2                                    
d1    d5                   v1                v5
d2    d6                   v2                v6
d3    d7                   v3                v7
d4    d8                   v4                v8
```

and reshape this as

```
                      Var1 Var2
date1 date2 lat  len           
d1    d5    lat1 len1   v1   v5
d2    d6    lat1 len1   v2   v6
d3    d7    lat1 len1   v3   v7
d4    d8    lat1 len1   v4   v8
```

to have those variables indexed by the lat and len values too.

Of course this is a small example, but I'm looking for something that could be valid for more variables (value always before '_') and latitudes and longitudes (values always between parenthesis and separated with a comma).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create `MultiIndex` with remove `()` first and then [`Series.str.split`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html) by `_` or `,`, so possible reshape by [`DataFrame.stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html), last set index names by [`DataFrame.rename_axis`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rename_axis.html):

```
df.columns = df.columns.str.replace('\(|\)','').str.split('_|, ', expand=True)
df = df.stack(level=[1,2]).rename_axis(('date1','date2','lat','len'))
print (df)

                      Var1 Var2
date1 date2 lat  len           
d1    d5    lat1 len1   v1   v5
d2    d6    lat1 len1   v2   v6
d3    d7    lat1 len1   v3   v7
d4    d8    lat1 len1   v4   v8
```

Comment: I got this error at my huge DataFrame: NotImplementedError: > 1 ndim Categorical are not supported at this time

Comment: @Angelo - How working `df.columns = df.columns.astype(str).str.replace('\(|\)','').str.split('_|, ', expand=True)` ?

Comment: Working perfect. It was a problem before that in my code. Thanks.